# how to update the edited data in the dhtmlxgrid to the database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I loaded the dhtmlxgrid from the database.I am able to edit the data in the grid also.i want that edited data has to store in my database.
 Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function everytime a cellValue is changed and write and update query.

```
 grid.attachEvent("onCellChanged", updateDatabase(rId,cInd,nValue){});
```

nValue will contain the new value of the cell. 
rId and cInd are the row- and column indexes of the changed cell.

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:event_oncellchanged